# Create alert pop-up with blank background screen

Tags: javascript, css

I need to display an alert box and at the same time cover what is on my HTML page. Basically, I'd like to have a blank or white background when my alert pop-up appears. I tried something like below, but doesn't work.

```
if (something happens) {

    changeBackgroundColor();

    if (alert("My alert box")){

    } else {
        //Return to previous page
        window.history.go(-1);
    }
}

..
....
.....

function changeBackgroundColor() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

Comment: `alert` btw does not return anything, since the user can only click okay. If you need your user to make a decision, `confirm` is the way to go. See here for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: You also want to remove the background color when alert goes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your background color will not hide any of the elements on your page. You will most likely need an overlay, which can be a simple div styled something like this:

```
.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:999; /* adjust the z-index as you need it */
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
}
```

you can then show the overlay before your alert and hide it afterwards

```
function toggleOverlay( show ){
    document.querySelector('.overlay').style.display = (show === true) ? 'block' : 'none';
}

// ...

toggleOverlay(true);
// Kudos to Kobe for pointing out that the alert is triggered before the repaint
// simple way to solve the problem is a timeout, which will
// make the browser paint the changes before the alert is triggered
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('Something');
    toggleOverlay(false);
}, 0);
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/UsernamesSuck/cpdrtgb8/2/

Comment: The idea works, but in execution it doesn't. The alert will trigger before the style changes.

Comment: I see, I didn't take that into account. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create an absolutely positioned div with a z-index greater than all of your content to hide it:

```js
const hide = () => {
  var div = document.getElementById('hide')
  div.style.display = 'block'
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert()
    div.style.display = 'none'
  }, 0)
}
```

```css
.hide {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Content Content Content</p>
<button onclick="hide()">HIDE</button>
<div id="hide" class="hide"></div>
```

> Since alert is blocking, you can immediately remove the style after the alert, which will take effect after the alert is closed.

Comment: I'd suggest setting position to fixed, since it's relative to the viewport. Otherwise, if the page is higher than the viewport and the user has scrolled down, the overlay won't cover the entire page. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/UsernamesSuck/x90ap362/1/

Comment: @Fitzi Good call, I forgot that absolute doesn't do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `alert()` is called the rest of the script pauses. A solution is to wrap it in a `setTimeout()` function to make it async to allow the rest of the code to be executed.

Take a look at the following Fiddle for a possible solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/hckevbtp/

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. I'm not using a button to trigger the alert, btw. I use if-then-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `display='none'` for the container and call the alert in `setTimeout()` as follows -

```
function openAlert() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0].style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('hello world!');
        document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0].style.display = 'block';
    }, 100);
}
```

html -

```
<body>
    <div class='block'>
        <button onclick={openAlert()}>hello</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> ```
> if (something happens) {
>
>     changeBackgroundColor();
>
>     setTimeout(function() {alert("hey");}, 0)
> }
>
> ..
> ....
> .....
>
> function changeBackgroundColor() {
>     document.body.style.opacity= "0";
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code:

```
    function showMessage() {
      var div = document.getElementById('div');
      if(div == null){
        div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = "div";
      }
      div.classList.add('alert')
      document.body.appendChild(div)
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("alert text");
        div.classList.remove('alert');
      },0)
    }
```

Style:

```
        .alert {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: white;
        }
```